# jena read rdf illegal type exception

Tags: java, rdf, jena, semantic-web

I am developing a jena based java program to read large rdf datasets (generated by Berlin Sparql Benchmark)
The file is of type .nt and I read it into model with this code

```
Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset(tdbPath);
Model model = dataset.getDefaultModel();
InputStream str = FileManager.get().open(data);

Boolean zipped = false;
if (data.substring(data.lastIndexOf('.')).equals(".gz")) 
{
    str = new GZIPInputStream(str);
    zipped = true;
}

model.read(str, null, "N-TRIPLES");
```

However after a few seconds, I receive the following consolse error

```
org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 10273787, col: 149] Illegal object: [DOUBLE:1862.25e0]
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: What is on line 10273787? And which version of the software are you running?

Comment: I have no idea about that, this is dummy data generated (However when I generate a ttl file it works). 
I am using apache jena 2.11.2

Comment: Well, the parse error is in the data at line 10273787. Without being able to see that line, it's impossible to say what the problem is. Upgrading to 2.13.0 might help.